# Prevent Ramda.omit from converting arrays into objects

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I'm using `R.omit` in a recursive function passing it both objects and arrays. The problem occurs when an array is passed to it, as it gets converted to an object:

```
const shouldBeArray = R.omit(['fill'])(['bla']);
```

Here `shouldBeArray` becomes `{ '0': 'bla' }`

How do I keep the arrays as arrays? This doesn't make much difference in the context of javascript, however when running the object through `JSON.stringify`, the structure becomes obviously different.

Here's the whole function:

```
  function removeColors(svgObj) {
    return R.when(
      R.is(Object),
      R.pipe(
        R.omit(['fill']),
        R.map(removeColors)
      )
    )(svgObj);
  }
```

Comment: You don't - the Ramda docs specify that the input should be an object, and Ramda has a "garbage in, garbage out" design philosophy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use R.unless to omit only if the object is not an array:

```js
const { curry, when, is, pipe, unless, omit, map } = R

const omitDeep = curry((keys, obj) => when(
  is(Object),
  pipe(
    unless(is(Array), omit(keys)),
    map(omitDeep(keys))
  )
)(obj))

const result = omitDeep(['fill'], {
  arr: ['bla'],
  p1: {
    arr: [{ fill: 'blue', background: 'red' }],
    fill: 'green'
  },
  fill: 'yellow'
})

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

Comment: really nice recursive use case

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`R.without()`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#without) or [`R.difference()`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#difference)

```js
console.log(R.without(['kromid'])(['bla']))

console.log(R.difference(['bla'])(['kromid']))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: There's a misunderstanding. My goal is to remove `kromid` members from objects, and ignore arrays.